# Calling overridden method of helper class in C++

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I come from a Python background, and currently I'm learning OOP in C++.

I'm having problems figuring out how to get the code to call the correct method in a helper class `HelperBase` that is inherited to `HelperChild`.

```
#include <iostream>

class HelperBase {
public:
    HelperBase() {}

    virtual void something() {
        std::cout << "HelperBase" << std::endl;
    }
};

class HelperChild : public HelperBase {
public:
    HelperChild() {}

    void something() {
        std::cout << "HelperChild" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The `HelperBase` class i used in the class `Base`, where it is set as a member variable.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(HelperBase &helperBase) : hb(helperBase) {}

    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << "-- Base" << std::endl;
        hb.something();
    }
    HelperBase hb;
};
```

Then this class is used as the base class of the class `Child`:

```
class Child : public Base {
public:
    Child(HelperChild &helperChild) : Base(helperChild) {
        helperChild.something();
    }
};
```

The `main` method is

```
int main() {
    HelperChild helperChild;

    Child child(helperChild);
    child.print();
    return 0;
}
```

*This outputs the following:*

```
HelperChild
-- Base
HelperBase
```

**Why isn't the 'HelperChild' printed in the last line? What changes do I have to do to achieve this?** (I'm not sure if I have used `virtual` in the correct way).

**EDIT:** In the actual case im trying to figure out, `Base::print` is a really large method that I don't want to override in the `Child` class. I just want to change the behaviour of the helper class.

Comment: `HelperBase hb;` is a `HelperBase`, it cannot hold an instance of `HelperChild`. You need to read about object slicing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy constructor will NOT copy derived object, it will get [sliced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28260481/4123703) and create a base object.

To elaborate, you may consider copy constructor as "copy by value", every value of derived object would be copied to create a base object. Since your Helper classes have no class members, it copied nothing.

Also function is not copyable, C++ handles virtual functions by [vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004501/why-do-we-need-virtual-table). A base class would have a vtable of base class, that's why hb.something() called the base version.

2. Last line is printing Helper base because your `Base` has a `HelperBase` but not a derived `HelperChild`.

---

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(HelperBase &helperBase) : hb(helperBase) {}  // hp(helperBase) means you still have a helper base.

    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << "-- Base" << std::endl;
        hb.something();
    }
    HelperBase hb;
};
```

Then in `main`, `child.print()` will call the hb.something() which belongs to `HelperBase`.

To achieve polymorphism, you need a pointer to take the instance of `HelperChild`. It's called Dependency Injection and I assumed you were trying to achieve it.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(HelperBase &helperBase) {
        hb = &helperBase;
    }

    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << "-- Base" << std::endl;
        hb->something();
    }
    HelperBase* hb;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HelperBase hb` in `class Base` is always of type `HelperBase` - even if you call `print` from an instance of type `Child`.
There are various ways to achieve what you want. One option is to use [PIMPL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) to store a pointer to a *Helper* class. A different option is to use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).